# How do you check if an user has successfully signed in after sending an Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, axios

In general after you send a JS ajax request to PHP backend , do i need to add http_response_code(201); after checking data user submitted is right in PHP code , so i can use then() in axios for example ? and if there is a problem in the submitted data i need to add http_response_code(401); so the catch() part will be fired is this http_response_code a must ? (i mean is that how it works?) cause i may want to check if its an internal server error (500) or just unauthorized user error (401) to show the convenient error message to the user. is that how its done in a professional project?

example :

JS:

```
axios.post('http://localhost/PHPFiles/UserAuthentification.php',null,config)
                    .then((response) => {
                        if(response.status == 200)
                        this.GetData();
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        if (error.response.status == 401) {
                              this.ShowUnauthorizedUserMessage();
                            }
                        if(error.response.status == 500){
                              this.ShowServerErrorMessage();
                            }
                    });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$serverName = "localhost";
$userName = "root";
$userPassword = "";
$dataBase = "todosdbs";
try{
$con = new mysqli($serverName,$userName,$userPassword,$dataBase);
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),false);
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT userid,username,userpassword,useremail FROM users WHERE useremail = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$data->currentUserEmailText);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
}catch(exception $e){
    http_response_code(500);
    die("server error");
}
if($result->num_rows>0){
    try{
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }catch(exception $e){
        http_response_code(500);
        die("server error!"); 
    }
    $pass = $row['userpassword'];
    if(password_verify($data->currentUserPasswordText,$pass)){
        http_response_code(200);
    }
    else{
        http_response_code(401);
        die("Unauthorized User!");
    }
}
else{
    http_response_code(401);
    die("Unauthorized User!");
}
?>
```

So is http_response_code(number); the way you check which code to execute next in client side from PHP backend ? one last question is 201 code the right one to inform client side a request was successfully implemented in the PHP backend like in my example or its 200 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it that way, but doing server-based error codes might be a bit heavy-handed for just validating user/pass. I personally just leave the response in an active state, as in if you hit the page you're looking for and the page knows what to do, I leave it as `200` and just send back a json array like so:

```
die(json_encode([
    # $valid would be a boolean based on your login/pass validation success
    'success' => $valid,
    # Depending on success, show appropriate msg
    'alert' => ($valid)? 'Successful login' : 'Invalid Username or Password',
    # Send back data if necessary
    'data' => false
]));
```

So it might look something more like:

**/functions.php**

```
<?php
function connect()
{
    return new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
}

function getUser($username, $con)
{
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE useremail = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    
    if($result->num_rows == 0)
        return false;

    return $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}

function userValid($user, $password)
{
    return password_verify($password, $user['userpassword']);
}

function ajaxResponse($success, $data = false, $msg = false)
{
    die(json_encode([
        'success' => $success,
        'data' => $data,
        'msg' => $msg,
    ]));
}
```

**/config.php**

```
<?php
define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__);
define('DB_HOST', "localhost");
define('DB_NAME', "todosdbs");
define('DB_USER', "root");
define('DB_PASS', "");
include(ROOT_DIR.'/functions.php');
```

**/PHPFiles/UserAuthentification.php**

```
<?php
include(__DIR__.'/../config.php');
# Send json header since that is what is returning
header('Content-Type: application/json');

try{
    # Fetch the database connection
    $con = connect();
    # Fetch the post
    $POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),false);
    # Fetch the user, inject username and db
    $user = getUser($POST->currentUserEmailText, $con);
    # Stop if username invalid
    if(!$user) {
        ajaxResponse(false, false, "Invalid user");
    }
    # Check validation
    $response = (userValid($user, $POST->currentUserPasswordText))? [
        'success' => true,
        'data' => $user,
        'msg' => 'User logged in successfully'
    ] : [
        'success' => false,
        'data' => false,
        'msg' => 'Invalid username or password'
    ];
    # Report back
    ajaxResponse(...$response);
}
catch(\Exception $e) {
    # Report back error if it occurs
    ajaxResponse(false, false, $e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using HTTP status codes (2xx for success, 4xx for errors,...) is great for giving a general idea about how the request went. Usually, you also want to put additional details in the response body, encoded so that the client can easily read them (for example JSON), to give clearer hints to clients about the error (and distinguish between all the possible outcomes!).

For example, a success response could have a 200 status code and have the following body:
`{"type":"sucess", "message": "User logged in successfully"}`

While an invalid login attempt would usually result in a 403 status code and the response could look like:
`{"type":"error", "message": "Invalid username or password"}`

But say you want to say whether an account with a given email exists or not (like Trello for example), then you will use a 403 status code for both responses, but with a distinct body:

```
{"type":"error", "message": "There is no account corresponding to the given email"}
{"type":"error", "message": "Invalid password"}
```

Using a 401 status code indicates the need to authenticate to access a resource, usually browsers will show a login prompt [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh2Sc.png) if the user browsed to this page (this will not apply to ajax requests though). Failed login attempts should get a 403 status code instead. You can check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors) for details about status codes and some hints about how browsers interpret them.

Side note: It seems you don't return any token nor set a cookie in case of a successful login, you most certainly want to do that to make sure the user is logged in in subsequent requests.

If you're looking for authentication examples, you can look at oAuth2 servers, or the [Firebase authentication API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/) for example.